# High Voltage(3kV) Capacitors & Relays -- Safety and Recommendations

Tags: capacitor, relay, high-voltage, safety

I am currently working on a quadrupole ion trap based on a DIY manual published by CERN.

Link: https://scoollab.web.cern.ch/3d-printable-quadrupole-ion-trap

Long story short, after failing to get my hands on the HV transformer required in the original setup, I am currently trying to produce the alternating high voltage using a HV capacitor and 4 HV relays arranged into a H bridge controlled by an Arduino. However, while I have worked with electronics (as a hobby) for a few years, this is my first HV project and thus I don't have a lot of knowledge about the components used in this field and the safety issues accompanied by the dangerous nature of HV. Below are a list of my questions:

**Note that if everything works just as planned, no current from the capacitor is ever needed. I only need the electric field for this project**

- How do you know/calculate how much voltage a big capacitor can generate when fully charged(or not fully charged)? And how do I choose the right big capacitor for my project? I needed to generate a roughly 3000v voltage difference for the ion trap to work.
- What are the safety gears(PPE and electronics wise) needed for a big HV capactior? I have only heard about big resistors used to safely discharge them, and have no idea if other stuff is needed.
- I need to switch the direction of the electric field 50 times a second, so a fast HV relay is probably needed, what are the recommended models for uses like this? It needs to be driven by 5v(or <12v if there are no 5v driven ones)
- I would probably need some safety resistors in the circuit in case there is an accidental breakdown in the ion trap itself and current is discharged from the capacitor. How big of a resistor do I need for that, like, rated for how many watts? Can ordinary ceramic resistors work or are there special ones? Or alternatively, can I use a fuse?

Thank you in advance------Wish Lin

Comment: If you are asking these questions, you are not experienced enough to do this safely. I recommend you STOP NOW

Comment: Electromechanical relays are *not* practical to run at those speeds, especially not high voltage ones.

Comment: A microwave oven transformer will give you 3kV or so. It can also kill you. I’d suggest you try to follow the instructions and source or make the transformer. As Hearth has commented, relays are not a valid solution. Besides 3kV relays would be much more expensive than a small transformer.

Comment: your post reads like `I want to climb Mount Everest.  I read that I'll need some rope and climbing boots. How much rope should I buy?`

Comment: 林韋旭, Find someone local who knows enough to help out and then both of you should contact the folks at CERN and ask some questions there before proceeding. Much more likely to succeed. Also, high voltage can be dangerous. And it doesn't seem as though you've read the materials there with understanding, quite yet. You don't need a relay and you'd know that fact if you'd read the PDF. So educate yourself about the project, safety, and methods before starting out. Find some skilled local help if possible. Also, their instructions are quite good and if you follow them carefully, you should be safe.

Comment: 林韋旭, Finally.... Don't let anyone tell you not to do something that you are motivated to do. That doesn't mean just jumping in, though. You should carefully read everything that project has handed to you -- it's very, very good and if you read it thoroughly you will have a very good idea about what's in front of you. Then think about the hazards you may face and study up a little about that, as well. In the process, you may have a specific question. (For example, they refer to a type of transformer, 1:200. You could ask us about that in the context of the experimental design.)

Comment: Chill the currents are very low .Do not do a big energy dangerous big cap .Remember that this is a non commercial site so some stuff  just wont appear,

Comment: @jonk I have thrououghly read the PDF and in fact, had already tried the exact setup mentioned in the PDF. However, Only after receiving the product did I notice the 24v to 3000v transformer I bought is for spot welders and takes a pretty big input power of 24v/2.5A to 3000v/?mA, which I consider too dangerous for a newbie like me, and I don't really believe they would allow high school students to operate that thing, so the transformer CERN uses probably has a higher impedance than mine(I guess). My friend came up with this capacitor idea and I wanted to thoroughly evaluate it before I try.

Comment: @jonk I have actually worked on it for quite a while now, gathering, making and buying the parts needed according to the PDF. The only safety hazard left is that transformer I mentioned above, which is also why I haven't fired it up yet, yes, maybe I am not experienced in high voltage setups but I DO understand the hazards and have worked with normal electronics for a few years now, so I want to make sure my first HV project is as safe as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily generate 30 kV with an automotive step-up pulse transformer and a HV transistor or rotary distributor contacts with a matched load cap.  But that won't make an ion trap.

For inductive loads, dry switching causes much higher arc voltages due to the V=LdI/dt When contacts begin to open, the attempt to separate is immediately followed by an arc since the tiny gap has a very low breakdown voltage and repeatedly at 50 Hz will burn out the contacts in minutes.

But magnetics are the approach to take after you define the electric field required and power level. **Define the requirements and keep looking for alternatives.**

If you want to verify dry contact arcing and trash a relay.... try this:

Get  any 12V automotive SPDT relay and a variable lab to supply the coil with the normally closed contacts in series with the coil.   You now have a buzzer and a high voltage output. The buzzer frequency increases with supply voltage slightly, while the contact surfaces are glowing yellow to white from the arcs.

http://www.vias.org/science_cartoons/img/gm_cartoon_iontrap.jpg